# Magento 2: requirejs-config.js in themes?

Tags: magento2, theme, javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to include a `requirejs-config.js` file (or otherwise configure RequireJS) via a Magento theme?  Or is the capability reserved for Magento modules?  The [dev docs information on theme structure](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) is ambiguous to this point.

Dev docs doesn't mention anything about RequireJS -- however, themes do include a `web` which means javascript can be bundled with them.  If javascript can be bundled with a theme, that means a RequireJS module can be bundled with a theme, and if a RequireJS module can be bundled with a theme that module may requires a specific RequireJS configuration.

My naive assumption would be themes **would** have this capability, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this one way or the other, and haven't an afternoon free to spend doing the required code spelunking on Magento's `requirejs-config.js` file including.

Comment: Hi @Alan. Can you please look into that ? => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253507/magenot-2-mixin-js-should-only-call-in-custom-module-page

Comment: @RohanHapaniNot really doing M2 development these days so I can't say top of head.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can actually include a require-config.js in your themes Module dirs.

The problem is (actually for our frontend team) that there seems to be no possibility, to override the config, but to extend the config.

So, to take the Magento_Theme module for an example here, if you add a require-config.js under `<theme_base_dir>/Magento_Theme` dir, the config will be added to the generated require-config.js file and also the config from the Magento_Theme module will be added.

To answer your question I also tried to add a require-config.js under the themes `<theme_base_dir>/web` dir and also under the themes root dir. Both did not work. **update: actually according to the answer below, it is possible by placing it into the theme base dir**

So the answer would be basically yes, since you could add any js requirement under any module (theme related js files may be best placed under the `<theme_base_dir>/Magento_Theme` dir)

Although I would say, there should be the possibility to add a theme related require-config.js outside of any Module (maybe you deactivate the given module) and also it should be possible to override a modules require-config.js.

Both seem not possible atm.

**===UPDATE===**

actually it seems possible to have a theme specific require-config.js. See @Gareth Daine's Answer below

Comment: Re: "under the Magento_Theme" could you be more explicit -- it's not 100% clear which folder in a theme and/or module your'e refering to.  Explicit meaning `path/to/theme/files/[etc/Magento_Theme`

Comment: I meant the acutal module override in your theme. So for the module Magento/Theme the require-config.js would be <theme_base_dir>/Magento_Theme/require-config.js where Magento_Theme is the actual module name

Comment: nice, updated the answer to make it more clear

Comment: So, am I right in thinking that a requirejs-config.js file does not work under app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/web/js?

Comment: It does say in the docs that JavaScript resources can be specified at the theme level for all libraries in app/design/{area}/{Vendor}/{theme}/web.

Comment: do you have a link to the documentation? I tried to include a require-config.js in the themes web dir but it did not work for me

Comment: Check my answer below. You're not supposed to place it in the web directory. It should go in your theme root directory.

Comment: ah ok, I'll update my answer with a hint to yours and at least give you an upvote for this :X

Answer (score 18):

OK, I think I may have solved it and I believe that the documentation is ambiguous and needs updating to clarify the process.

I moved my `requirejs-config.js`from within the `web/js` and `web` directories respectively for both `Magento_Theme` and the root of my theme at `<Vendor>/<theme>` and now my RequireJS config is merged into the main `requirejs-config.js` with all other includes.

So, it appears that you have to include the `requirejs-config.js` file in the following locations based on the theme/module requirements.

**Theme Level**

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js`

**Module Level**

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<Module_Name>/requirejs-config.js`

So, in your `requirejs-config.js` for your theme you should map your component to a path and then use `shim` to declare any dependencies:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        'component': 'js/component'
    },
    shim: {
        'component': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Then you'll need to create a template to hold the initialisation of the components via a `<script>` tag (unless you attach it directly to an element within a .phtml file) if this is the route you want to go down, include the following content:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "js/component": {} // Not entirely sure what {} is and what I'm passing here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, bind it to an element:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#element": {
            "js/component": {} // Not entirely sure what {} is and what I'm passing here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then simply include the .phtml template in your layout instructions, for example, I placed mine within the `default.xml` located at `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout` under the body node and referenced:

`<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="theme.js" template="Magento_Theme::html/js.phtml" />`

Comment: The {} in "js/component": {} is used to pass options to the component

Comment: This should be considered the right answer.

As a completement, **if you want to init the component from a .phtml** just add the following: `<script type="text/javascript" > require(['js/component']); </script>`.

Feel free to use if/else validation in PHP as you required.

Answer (score 5):

Yes `requirejs-config.js` can be added to theme as follow. This is how I add dotdotdot library in my magento2 custom theme.

**1. Download and add Js Library in your theme following the path:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js
```

**2. Create a theme's requirejs file as follow and let the requirejs know newly added library.**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dotdotdot: 'js/jquery.dotdotdot.min',
       }
   }
};
```

**3. Use the added library in your theme's main js file as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/main.js
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

**4. and include your theme's js file in your site's head as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

You can add any external JS library and custom file on every page in magento2.

Comment: I tried adding a library via the `requirejs-config.js` this way. However, RequireJS then tries to load `js/some.library.js` from the root instead of from the theme directory.

Comment: Ah, you have to omit the `.js` extension... silly :)

Answer (score 3):

Didn't have sufficient rep to make this a comment, but just to note that Gareth's answer didn't quite work for me.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'component': 'js/component'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'component': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Wrapping the 'component': 'js/component' with `'*':{}` did the trick.

Also rather than create a template file I added the code below at the top of `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="jquery.bootstrap">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*":{"jquery.bootstrap":{}}}</script>]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```