# How To add JS file in frontend for all pages

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I've read 3 pages of Google Results on how to load a JS file for all pages and still am not able to do it.

I've got a few doubts, hope somebody can clear them out.

1. Do I need to create a module inside `app/code` with the `requirejs-config.js` ? Or I can put a `requirejs-config.js` inside my theme instead?
2. What should I put inside `requirejs-config.js` ?
3. What should the code look like inside my `.js` file? I saw that you can't use jQuery's `document.ready` and you must have a `define([`
4. What should I put inside `define([` ?
5. If I've got third party jQuery modules, do I have to edit them to make them work?
6. Do I need to put xml somewhere to tell magento that my.js file exists?
7. If I create a module inside `app/code` with all the js code there, would it include all the stuff in all pages? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 86):

To load a custom `main.js` file on all pages (in the RequireJS-way) this is a good way:

**1) Create `main.js`**

Create `main.js` within the theme folder

`<theme_dir>/web/js/main.js`

with this content:

```
define([
  "jquery"
], 
function($) {
  "use strict";

  // Here your custom code...
  console.log('Hola');

});
```

*In short*: we declare dependencies at the start, e.g. `"jquery"`. We define as function's parameter the variable name for using the dependency within the function, e.g. `"jquery" --> $`. We put all our custom code within `function($) { ... }`.

**2) Declare `main.js` with a `requirejs-config.js` file**

Create a `requirejs-config.js` file within the theme folder:

`<theme_dir>/requirejs-config.js`

with this content:

```
var config = {

  // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
  deps: [
    "js/main"
  ]

};
```

`"js/main"` is the path to our custom `main.js`. The ".js" extension is not required.

Our `requirejs-config.js` will be merged with other `requirejs-config.js` defined in Magento.

RequireJS will load our `main.js` file, on each page, resolving dependencies and loading files in an async way.

---

### Optional: Including third-party library

This is the way to include third-party libraries.

**1)** Add the library in `web/js`:

`<theme_dir>/web/js/vendor/jquery/slick.min.js`

**2)** Open `requirejs-config.js` and add this content:

```
var config = {

  deps: [
    "js/main"
  ],

  // Paths defines associations from library name (used to include the library,
  // for example when using "define") and the library file path.
  paths: {
    'slick': 'js/vendor/jquery/slick.min',
  },

  // Shim: when you're loading your dependencies, requirejs loads them all
  // concurrently. You need to set up a shim to tell requirejs that the library
  // (e.g. a jQuery plugin) depends on another already being loaded (e.g. depends
  // on jQuery).
  // Exports: if the library is not AMD aware, you need to tell requirejs what 
  // to look for so it knows the script has loaded correctly. You can do this with an 
  // "exports" entry in your shim. The value must be a variable defined within
  // the library.
  shim: {
    'slick': {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: 'jQuery.fn.slick',
    }
  }

};
```

It looks more complicated than what it actually is.

**3)** Add the dependency within `main.js`:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'slick'
], 
function($) {

  // ...

});
```

Comment: Hi , Can you tell if I have to include bootstrap.js here. How can I add it so that bootstrap works well in my theme. Thanks!

Comment: @anujeet You can include `bootstrap.js` in the same way I included `slick.js` in the above example. For the shim value you can try to use this: `'bootstrap': { deps: ["jquery"], exports: '$.fn.popover' }`, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13556882/3763649

Comment: See my require-config.js

`var config = { 
 deps: [
  "js/animate",
  "js/incase",
  "js/confetti"
 ],
    paths: {
  "jquery.bootstrap":"js/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim:{
      'jquery.bootstrap':{
  'deps':['jquery']
      }
    }
};


require(["jquery",'jquery.bootstrap', 'jquery/ui', 'jquery/validate', 'mage/validation/validation', 'domReady!']);`


My minicart stops working with this

Comment: @anujeet Better you open another question with this issue, reporting your require-config.js and if you have some errors in the javascript console. If you link your question here I will be glad to help you :)

Comment: when include more js I have errors

        "js/ScrollMagic.min",
        "js/debug.addIndicators.min"

Comment: method 1 when I modify main.js not see modify

Obbligatory run content:deploy?

Comment: Man, you saved my life. Works fine here. Thanks

Comment: slick css files ?

Comment: @Andrea i want to load the js on particular pages only can you check my question  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210440/call-custom-js-to-particular-page-only-magento-2/210448?noredirect=1#comment292910_210448

Comment: @Andrea, can I place my custom.js file in media/pub/pmm-custom instead of <theme_dir>/web/js/?

Answer (score 6):

Duplicate the file:

> app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

To

> app/code/*your_vendor*/*your_theme*/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>

        <!-- Add external resources -->
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

For more information:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

Good luck!

BTW
read the frontend devdocs official from magento to get the basic :)

Comment: Because Bootstrap's script requires JQuery to be initialized, including it in the head won't work. Read [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html#m2devgde-js-resources-dependencies) official doc. for more info. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can add JS files using xml as below. This will add js in all the pages.

**With custom module:**

Create `default.xml` file in your module.

`app/code/vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <!-- Add js using link tag-->
        <link src="js/script.js"/>

        <!-- Add js-->
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/script.js"/>

        <!-- Add external js -->
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" src_type="url" />
   </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

The method of adding js using the `default_head_blocks.xml` file will not work for 3rd party JQuery plugins. So, if you want to add custom JQuery plugins and use them, you will need to use `requirejs-config.js` file.

To answer your questions one by one:

1) & 2) You don't need to create a module to add the `requirejs-config.js` file. You can just add it in this location:

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js`

Refer to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103070/32459) to creating a proper `requirejs-config.js` file.

3) You will need to list the dependencies of your js file before you write your scripts.

```
require([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui'
], function($){
   // ... Your code here
});
```

The above code says that you will need jquery and jquery ui for your scripts.

4) You don't need to use the `define([` unless you are creating a javascript plugin.

5) No, you don't need to edit them but you will need to specify their dependency using the `requirejs-config.js` file. If you have `owl.carousel.min.js` in `<vendor>/<theme>/web/js/owl.carousel.min.js`, your `requirejs-config.js` file will look like this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            owlCarouselTheme: 'js/owl.carousel.min'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        owlCarouselTheme: ['jquery']
    }
};
```

In the above code, please remember that there is no `.js` for the file.
And now to use it in your js

```
require(['jquery', 'owlCarouselTheme'],function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".footer.links").addClass("owl-carousel").owlCarousel({items: 1});
    });
})
```

If everything works well, you should have your footer links in a slider.

6) & 7) Just use the method suggested by @Goldy to add your js. It will add your js file to all the pages.

For further reading, you can look at this [post](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/custom-javascript-in-magento-2-with-requirejs/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please kindly have a look at a similar issue that I am facing with custom JS here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312363/how-to-call-a-function-in-a-custom-js-file-from-within-another-custom-js-file

Answer (score 2):

> **Load a JS file for all pages**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="VendorName_ModuleName::js/main_all_page.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**main_all_page.js**

```
require(["jquery"],
    function($){

    alert("JS file for all pages ");
    console.log("JS file for all pages ");

})
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add dotdotdot library in my magento2 custom theme.

**1. Download and add Js Library in your theme following the path:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js
```

**2. Create a theme's requirejs file as follow and let the requirejs know newly added library.**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dotdotdot: 'js/jquery.dotdotdot.min',
       }
   }
};
```

**3. Use the added library in your theme's main js file as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/main.js
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

**4. and include your theme's js file in your site's head as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

You can add any external JS library and custom file on every page in magento2.

Comment: I have tried this is admin side, js is coming correctly but expected result is not coming

Comment: Nice answer. Gonna try it. Is there a way to specify a certain page where the js file is needed.?

Comment: For a specific page, move the "default_head_blocks.xml" content in above example to your specific layout file. For example in case of product detail page, add that xml in  app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: @saiid, Is this a better way to include a sinle custom JS in the header than overriding header.phtml

Comment: @CodeForGood yes it is always better to follow the practice that Magento recommends. Like you never know in future you're going to add more custom JS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

May be this one help anyone,
add this code to your default.xml file

you can add this to your theme or your module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="Company_Module::js/custom.js"/>
</head>
</page>
```

your custom.js file would reside in the location
**app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simple way that requires no coding and no editing - go to Admin->Content->Configuration-> Select Website and Edit -> HTML Head and include  or  tag here, you can insert CSS also here.