# M2.1 Auto open shipping summary in cart

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping

Currently when customer navigates to checkout, they have to click the shipping options of the sidebar in order to display and subsequently select a shipping option.  How can we make it so that these shipping options open automatically when the cart page loads, so that they are instantly visible to the user.

Following [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141693/magento-2-auto-open-cart-items-on-checkout-index-page) but it appears to only affect the cart items further along the checkout process.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the below works with 2.2.0

The principle of the below is the same as the checkout solution, only difference is that it's a different file. If you haven't already done so, copy the shipping.phtml file to your theme into the below path:

```
Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/shipping.phtml
```

line 12, change:

```
<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": true}}'>
```

to

```
<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "active": "active", "saveState": true}}'>
```

alternatively if you don't want it collapsible change it to the below

```
<div id="block-shipping" class="block shipping">
```