# Magento 2.2.5 checkout page summary discount row shows as expanded

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5

In Magento2.2.5 using the default Magento2 2 step checkout on the payment & review step in the order summary box the discount which I believe is suppose to be a drop down shows always as expanded and I would like it not to always be expanded by default. See the screenshot below. Where and how do I make that not be auto-expanded? I looked in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary` but not sure what file would be edited and how. of course I will move the file to my theme once I know which one needs to be edited.
see screenshot

[image]

Thank you @fmsthird I moved the file from Vendor to my theme folder which happens to be

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Checkout/templates/summary
```

I then recompiled and redeployed and flushed magento cache but I dont see any change.

My first row in the cart-items.phtml looks like this

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'false', 'false': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141693/magento-2-how-to-auto-open-cart-items-on-checkout-page

Answer (score 1):

You can check **`cart-items.html`** from the path below:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html
```

Look for the **`openedState`** attribute  and change the **`active`** state to **`false`**.

Comment: please see my updated on the bottom of my original message. Thanks

Comment: Try like `<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': 'false'}}">`

Comment: No I tried compiling deploying and flushing cache but I don't think that file controls the "discount" line that i am trying to make be collapsed.

Comment: I want just the line that says "Discount" to be collapsed

Comment: @fmsthird please answer this too https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279918/how-to-add-a-additional-field-in-summary-section-magento-2-3

Comment: Let me check...