# Magento 2: How to use event trigger on the checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, jquery, drop-downs

**How to use event trigger when change "State/Province " drop-down on the checkout page?**

I'm trying to page reload when user change Region from **"State/Province"** dropdown in the checkout page.

First, I've created js file and put code and this js add in frontend using [article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages) but it's not worked

also, I have put static JS file in XML file but there give a JQuery not defined error.
 see below js file code

```
define([
   "jquery",
],
function($) {
   "use strict";
    $('document').on('change', 'select[name="region_id"]', function(){
       alert("hi");
    });
return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put an alert('test'); in your js file or check in debugger tool whether your js is getting called or not, if it gets called then use this in you file:

```
jQuery('document').on('change', '**identifier-of-the-field**', function(){
   //opertation to be performed
});
```

Comment: alert('test'); is working fine but when i put "jQuery('document').on('change..." code give a error " jQuery is not defined"

Comment: can you show your js file?

Comment: or you can use **$** in place of **jQuery**

Comment: you used jquery in magento 2 standard format. So it will not give error like not defined.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: @DhirenVasoya can you give me example link for magento2 standard?