# Add js to magento head in frontend and adminhtml without creating a requirejs module and loading last on module

Tags: magento2, module, frontend

I'm trying to add a simple js that has to be executed on documentReady with jQuery.

Script js

```
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!',
], function ($) {
   //Script code
});
```

Also, it needs to be on a module, not a theme, on every page, adminhtml and frontend.
I've tried adding the script with a default.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <head>
        <link src="Custom_Iframe::js/iframe.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

However, this puts the script before every other script, including require-js and jQuery.

I know i can make it a module and then a block that loads the module, but i cannot understand how to do that, and i've been on the second page of google checking for answers on multiple searches.

I've also tried this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131635, but then, the script never gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in

`app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{ThemePackage}/Magento_Theme/view/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- some code-->

        <!-- for including css -->
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/some.css"/>
        <!-- for including js -->

        <link src="Magento_Theme::js/slider/some.js"/>

        <!-- some code-->
    </head>
</page>
```