# How to include Materialize framework into Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to use Materialize framework in Magento 2.

As per the documentation, to add external css/js resources I edited default_head_blocks.xml as

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!-- Add local resources -->
    <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

    <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>

    <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js" src_type="url" />
</head>
```

Now I'm getting the error as "Module name "jquery" has not been loaded yet". Screenshot below[image]

Is there any better way to include the files? Need some help...

Answer (score 1):

As to the docu of materialize.js you have to import jquery first.
Thus you have to use requireJs to load materialize.js

You can read here how to do so: [How To add JS file in frontend for all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages)

Here is the documentation on how to do so:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html