# Adding Custom JS to Magento 2 Theme

Tags: magento2, javascript

Im following the answer provide by Andrea on [How To add JS file in frontend for all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages)

However I am recieving the follow error and unsure how to resolve?

require.js:1895 GET http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497347169/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/js/main.js

require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: js/main
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Could anyone please help with getting a custom script added?

Update:

I've tried to include libraries into my require_config.js like:

```
var config = {
paths: {  
        'accessible-menu': "Magento_Theme/js/accessible-menu/accessible-menu",
        'slick': "Magento_Theme/js/slick/slick.min"
    },   
shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'accessible-menu': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

And have added my main scripts file into my default.xml like:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="scripts.min.js">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.dev/app/design/frontend/aa/aa-theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/scripts.min.js"></script>]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Just doesn't seem to be loading the libraries but my scripts.min.js is included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you done the following?

- Clear Magento cache
- Clear browser cache
- Delete the following directory

  - `var/pre_processed`
  - `pub/static/frontend`
  - `pub/static/_requirejs`
- Reload the page

The majority of the time I see errors like this it's because of caching and/or symlinks.

### Update

Thanks for including your code, I think this is happening because you are adding JS via XML. This is no longer the best way to add JS in Magento, you should take a look at [Require JS](http://requirejs.org/).

The `require_config.js` does not load JS file, all you've done there is add aliases and dependencies for your scripts.

To load an actual script you need to use either `x-magento-init` or `data-mage-init`. Read [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html) for the full info.

I think you need to do something along these lines:

**In your PHTML template:**

Replace `*` with your element ID/Class.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
            "slick": {}
    }
}
</script>
```

**Initialise Slick**
Initialise Slick in here.

```
define(['jquery', 'slick', 'domReady!'], function($, slick) {
    'use strict';

    $('.your-element').slick();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately didn't have no luck :(

Comment: @heady12 I've updated my answer after seeing your code.

Comment: Ben Sir I'm getting the same issue can you please look at my issue as well https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293270/how-to-disable-province-zipcode-and-country-from-checkout-magento-2-2

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add dotdotdot library in my magento2 custom theme.

**1. Download and add Js Library in your theme following the path:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js
```

**2. Create a theme's requirejs file as follow and let the requirejs know newly added library.**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dotdotdot: 'js/jquery.dotdotdot.min',
       }
   }
};
```

**3. Use the added library in your theme's main js file as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/main.js
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

**4. and include your theme's js file in your site's head as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

You can add any external JS library and custom file on every page in magento2.

Comment: When I used domReady and  $(window).load in Checkout page, my custom script didn't execute..

Comment: Can I see the full js script if you're still facing the issue?