# How to Disable province , zipcode and country from checkout. Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, checkout-page

In Magento2 - I want to remove ***ZipCode*** , ***Province*** and ***Country*** name from the Checkout page for which I tried

> Vender/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {

    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
             'ALP_Checkout/js/view/shipping': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
], function(
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;

    setInterval(() => {
        if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').addClass('hidden');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').removeClass('_required');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').find('input').val("64000");
        }
        if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').addClass('hidden');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').removeClass('_required');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').find('input').val("removedFromFrontend");
        }
        if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').addClass('hidden');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').removeClass('_required');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').find('select').val("PK");
        }
        if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').addClass('hidden');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').find('select').val("102");
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').removeClass('_required');
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').find('input').val("removedFromFrontend");
        }
    }, 1000);

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),

        /**
         * @return {exports}
         */
        initialize: function() {
            var self = this,
                hasNewAddress,
                fieldsetName = 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset';

            this._super();

            if (!quote.isVirtual()) {
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    'shipping',
                    '',
                    $t('Shipping'),
                    this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    10
                );
            }
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingAddress();

            hasNewAddress = addressList.some(function(address) {
                return address.getType() == 'new-customer-address'; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            });

            this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);

            this.isFormPopUpVisible.subscribe(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    self.getPopUp().openModal();
                }
            });

            quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function() {
                self.errorValidationMessage(false);
            });

            registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function(checkoutProvider) {
                var shippingAddressData = checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData();

                if (shippingAddressData) {
                    checkoutProvider.set(
                        'shippingAddress',
                        $.extend(true, {}, checkoutProvider.get('shippingAddress'), shippingAddressData)
                    );
                }
                checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function(shippingAddrsData) {
                    checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddrsData);
                });
                shippingRatesValidator.initFields(fieldsetName);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Navigator change hash handler.
         *
         * @param {Object} step - navigation step
         */
        navigate: function(step) {
            step && step.isVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getPopUp: function() {
            var self = this,
                buttons;

            if (!popUp) {
                buttons = this.popUpForm.options.buttons;
                this.popUpForm.options.buttons = [{
                        text: buttons.save.text ? buttons.save.text : $t('Save Address'),
                        class: buttons.save.class ? buttons.save.class : 'action primary action-save-address',
                        click: self.saveNewAddress.bind(self)
                    },
                    {
                        text: buttons.cancel.text ? buttons.cancel.text : $t('Cancel'),
                        class: buttons.cancel.class ? buttons.cancel.class : 'action secondary action-hide-popup',

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        click: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                    }
                ];

                /** @inheritdoc */
                this.popUpForm.options.closed = function() {
                    self.isFormPopUpVisible(false);
                };

                this.popUpForm.options.modalCloseBtnHandler = this.onClosePopUp.bind(this);
                this.popUpForm.options.keyEventHandlers = {
                    escapeKey: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                };

                /** @inheritdoc */
                this.popUpForm.options.opened = function() {
                    // Store temporary address for revert action in case when user click cancel action
                    self.temporaryAddress = $.extend(true, {}, checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData());
                };
                popUp = modal(this.popUpForm.options, $(this.popUpForm.element));
            }

            return popUp;
        },

        /**
         * Revert address and close modal.
         */
        onClosePopUp: function() {
            checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData($.extend(true, {}, this.temporaryAddress));
            this.getPopUp().closeModal();
        },

        /**
         * Show address form popup
         */
        showFormPopUp: function() {
            this.isFormPopUpVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * Save new shipping address
         */
        saveNewAddress: function() {
            var addressData,
                newShippingAddress;

            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();

            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;

                // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress($.extend(true, {}, addressData));
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Shipping Method View
         */
        rates: shippingService.getShippingRates(),
        isLoading: shippingService.isLoading,
        isSelected: ko.computed(function() {
            return quote.shippingMethod() ?
                quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'] + '_' + quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'] :
                null;
        }),

        /**
         * @param {Object} shippingMethod
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        selectShippingMethod: function(shippingMethod) {
            selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code']);

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Set shipping information handler
         */
        setShippingInformation: function() {
            if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {
                setShippingInformationAction().done(
                    function() {
                        stepNavigator.next();
                    }
                );
            }
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        validateShippingInformation: function() {
            var shippingAddress,
                addressData,
                loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',
                emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                field;

            if (!quote.shippingMethod()) {
                this.errorValidationMessage($t('Please specify a shipping method.'));

                return false;
            }

            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }

            if (this.isFormInline) {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();

                if (emailValidationResult &&
                    this.source.get('params.invalid') ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'] ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code']
                ) {
                    this.focusInvalid();

                    return false;
                }

                shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                addressData = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                    this.source.get('shippingAddress')
                );

                //Copy form data to quote shipping address object
                for (field in addressData) {
                    if (addressData.hasOwnProperty(field) && //eslint-disable-line max-depth
                        shippingAddress.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                        typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        _.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])
                    ) {
                        shippingAddress[field] = addressData[field];
                    } else if (typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        !_.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])) {
                        shippingAddress = addressData;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    shippingAddress['save_in_address_book'] = 1;
                }
                selectShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
            }

            if (!emailValidationResult) {
                $(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').focus();

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Trigger Shipping data Validate Event.
         */
        triggerShippingDataValidateEvent: function() {
            this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

            if (this.source.get('shippingAddress.custom_attributes')) {
                this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.custom_attributes.data.validate');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It returns me a **Blank Page** of Checkout. What is the problem and how can I sort this
[image: Blank Page]

Comment: Do you want to just hide those fields or permanently remove from checkout?

Comment: just want to hide... like I explained you before that for current situation we only need it for Pakistan

Comment: when I apply this code then it returns me a blank checkout page

Comment: I hide the values and fix the values for them as you can see in the code clearly

Comment: You can remove those field from layoutProcessor.php only

Comment: I dont want to remove I want to hide this

Comment: If you hide zipcode...It is required field and it didn't allow to proceed

Comment: I hide these things and set the fix values for these like I hide the country and I set the value of country of PK by default

Comment: currently the issue I have is that checkout page is blank... as you can see above in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100108/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-asad-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

use map instead of mixins to override code js files

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping':'Vendor_Checkout/js/view/shipping'
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

Add your custom logic like `customFunction`

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
], function(
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;



    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),

        /**
         * @return {exports}
         */
        initialize: function() {
            var self = this,
                hasNewAddress,
                fieldsetName = 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset';
            this.customFunction();//Call your function here to run when page loads
            this._super();

            if (!quote.isVirtual()) {
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    'shipping',
                    '',
                    $t('Shipping'),
                    this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    10
                );
            }
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingAddress();

            hasNewAddress = addressList.some(function(address) {
                return address.getType() == 'new-customer-address'; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            });

            this.isNewAddressAdded(hasNewAddress);

            this.isFormPopUpVisible.subscribe(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    self.getPopUp().openModal();
                }
            });

            quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(function() {
                self.errorValidationMessage(false);
            });

            registry.async('checkoutProvider')(function(checkoutProvider) {
                var shippingAddressData = checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData();

                if (shippingAddressData) {
                    checkoutProvider.set(
                        'shippingAddress',
                        $.extend(true, {}, checkoutProvider.get('shippingAddress'), shippingAddressData)
                    );
                }
                checkoutProvider.on('shippingAddress', function(shippingAddrsData) {
                    checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(shippingAddrsData);
                });
                shippingRatesValidator.initFields(fieldsetName);
            });

            return this;
        },

        customFunction: function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').removeClass('_required');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.postcode"]').find('input').val("64000");
                }
                if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').removeClass('_required');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region"]').find('input').val("removedFromFrontend");
                }
                if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').removeClass('_required');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"]').find('select').val("PK");
                }
                if (!$('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').addClass('hidden');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').find('select').val("102");
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').removeClass('_required');
                    $('div[name="shippingAddress.region_id"]').find('input').val("removedFromFrontend");
                }
            }, 1000);
        },

        /**
         * Navigator change hash handler.
         *
         * @param {Object} step - navigation step
         */
        navigate: function(step) {
            step && step.isVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getPopUp: function() {
            var self = this,
                buttons;

            if (!popUp) {
                buttons = this.popUpForm.options.buttons;
                this.popUpForm.options.buttons = [{
                        text: buttons.save.text ? buttons.save.text : $t('Save Address'),
                        class: buttons.save.class ? buttons.save.class : 'action primary action-save-address',
                        click: self.saveNewAddress.bind(self)
                    },
                    {
                        text: buttons.cancel.text ? buttons.cancel.text : $t('Cancel'),
                        class: buttons.cancel.class ? buttons.cancel.class : 'action secondary action-hide-popup',

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        click: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                    }
                ];

                /** @inheritdoc */
                this.popUpForm.options.closed = function() {
                    self.isFormPopUpVisible(false);
                };

                this.popUpForm.options.modalCloseBtnHandler = this.onClosePopUp.bind(this);
                this.popUpForm.options.keyEventHandlers = {
                    escapeKey: this.onClosePopUp.bind(this)
                };

                /** @inheritdoc */
                this.popUpForm.options.opened = function() {
                    // Store temporary address for revert action in case when user click cancel action
                    self.temporaryAddress = $.extend(true, {}, checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData());
                };
                popUp = modal(this.popUpForm.options, $(this.popUpForm.element));
            }

            return popUp;
        },

        /**
         * Revert address and close modal.
         */
        onClosePopUp: function() {
            checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData($.extend(true, {}, this.temporaryAddress));
            this.getPopUp().closeModal();
        },

        /**
         * Show address form popup
         */
        showFormPopUp: function() {
            this.isFormPopUpVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * Save new shipping address
         */
        saveNewAddress: function() {
            var addressData,
                newShippingAddress;

            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();

            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;

                // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress($.extend(true, {}, addressData));
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Shipping Method View
         */
        rates: shippingService.getShippingRates(),
        isLoading: shippingService.isLoading,
        isSelected: ko.computed(function() {
            return quote.shippingMethod() ?
                quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'] + '_' + quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'] :
                null;
        }),

        /**
         * @param {Object} shippingMethod
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        selectShippingMethod: function(shippingMethod) {
            selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code']);

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Set shipping information handler
         */
        setShippingInformation: function() {
            if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {
                setShippingInformationAction().done(
                    function() {
                        stepNavigator.next();
                    }
                );
            }
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        validateShippingInformation: function() {
            var shippingAddress,
                addressData,
                loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',
                emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                field;

            if (!quote.shippingMethod()) {
                this.errorValidationMessage($t('Please specify a shipping method.'));

                return false;
            }

            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }

            if (this.isFormInline) {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();

                if (emailValidationResult &&
                    this.source.get('params.invalid') ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'] ||
                    !quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code']
                ) {
                    this.focusInvalid();

                    return false;
                }

                shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                addressData = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                    this.source.get('shippingAddress')
                );

                //Copy form data to quote shipping address object
                for (field in addressData) {
                    if (addressData.hasOwnProperty(field) && //eslint-disable-line max-depth
                        shippingAddress.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                        typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        _.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])
                    ) {
                        shippingAddress[field] = addressData[field];
                    } else if (typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                        !_.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])) {
                        shippingAddress = addressData;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    shippingAddress['save_in_address_book'] = 1;
                }
                selectShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
            }

            if (!emailValidationResult) {
                $(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').focus();

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Trigger Shipping data Validate Event.
         */
        triggerShippingDataValidateEvent: function() {
            this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.data.validate');

            if (this.source.get('shippingAddress.custom_attributes')) {
                this.source.trigger('shippingAddress.custom_attributes.data.validate');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sir Did I need to call my `customFunction()` or it will run by default?

Comment: I called inside the `initialize` function.

Comment: it give me an error `console-output-handler.js:34 [2019-10-21 05:48:00] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping" component.`

Comment: n still returns nothing

Comment: did you run the setup:upgrade and content-deploy command?

Comment: yeah I run both of these commands

Comment: Not possible..I ran those in my site.and working fine

Comment: let me delete generated

Comment: it runs but I dont think so that it runs my `shipping.js` file coz when I `console.log('testing')` something then it do not show testing in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100113/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-asad-khan).

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297805/how-to-change-a-shipping-method-config-error-message-by-custom-module-custom-mes