# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 199

Tags: magento2, javascript, fatal-error, requirejs, console

I tried to add a main.js to my Magento theme using the answer on [How To add JS file in frontend for all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages), however, it caused issues so I removed this, however, I still get console error for this.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 199
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at getData (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/mage/apply/main.js:51:24)
at Array.map (native)
at HTMLDocument.apply (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/mage/apply/main.js:67:18)
at fire (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery.js:3232:32)
at Object.add [as done] (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery.js:3291:8)
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery.js:3542:26)
at jQuery.fn.init (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery.js:2967:11)
at jQuery.fn.init (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:225:17)
at jQuery (http://domain.dev/products/pub/static/version1497885161/frontend/aa/aa-theme/en_US/jquery.js:75:11)
```

I've tried to resolve this by removing the contents of pub/static and ran the PHP bin/magento setup:static-content: deploy but the console error still appears and is causing all javascript elements on my Magento site to not work.

Comment: Just had this myself. My cause was because I left a rogue ,  at the end of some JSON configuration in one of my templates for a knockout component.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing browser cache if you haven't already, I've had this a few times when I forgot to clear it.

Also make sure you have un-done the steps you took to add it, so remove the related JS from the require JS config to.

Comment: Yeah i've cleared both Magento and browser caches. I've completely removed it from the theme but I'm not 100% sure whether this is from the main.js I tried to add or others as I searched the complete site and there are still references to main.js in other 'core?' files.

Answer (score 0):

Remove pub/static folder content  and /var/view_processed or 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade (this remove all static content) ,then deploy

Comment: Unfortunately didn't resolve my error :( Do i need to re-run Magento compile command when it asks?

Comment: Which thing you have done can you write step

Comment: Ive tried removing pub/static contents and /var/view_processed/ then ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.

Also tried to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade, but didn't run the compile command when it asked, just ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy. 

I then cleared cache by php bin/magento cache:flush but error still showing.

Comment: Just tired this again and ran the compile command when it asks, but still no luck :(

Comment: 1) remove var/view_processed

Comment: 2)then setup:upgrade 3)then deploy and check with clear browser cache

Comment: Still no luck :/ sorry :(