# Include js file in system.xml

Tags: magento2, javascript, system.xml

I have a file: `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` where I have added some form fields. However I need to add a custom script being executed while someone types in one of the fields.

How can I include a .js in this page?
It appears I can't simply include it like I would do in a simple xml magento 2 page

```
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::test.css"/>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::test.js"/>
</head>
```

Comment: This may help - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages

Comment: It does. I actually used `requirejs-config.js` (I posted it as a reply below). However in my case I wish to include the .js file only in the system page of my module, not in every single page of the admin panel. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't do any work in the admin so I can't help with that sorry, is there not layout XML you can use for the admin to target a specific page?

Comment: I haven't found anything yet. The `view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` that was suggested in the first reply didn't work... I keep searching though

Comment: I just added the file `view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js` with my own code inside and it seems to be loaded in every single page of the admin panel. I don't like this practice, but it's the only thing working right now.

I also get this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at requirejs-config.js:423
    at requirejs-config.js:424
    at requirejs-config.js:428
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:423
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:424
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:428`

Answer (score 4):

Create in one of your extensions the file `view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` and put your  content in there.
`adminhtml_system_config_edit` is the layout handle for the configuration page.

Comment: Thank you but can you be more detailed? I don't have any files on the `view/adminhtml` folder, as my only page is set at the `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` so how do I declare that the system.xml has an external test.js file? I tried what you said and added file `view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` with the code: `<layout version="0.1.0"> <adminhtml_system_config_edit> <reference name="head"> <action method="addJs"><file>test.js</file></action> </reference> </adminhtml_system_config_edit> </layout>` but it wasn't included in the output

Comment: Maybe I should add the .js and .css in the `etc/acl.xml` file, or the `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` file?

Comment: you cannot add js and css files from the system or acl xml files. They serve different purposes. You can add resources from the layout files as explained in the answer. For every configuration page the layout files named `adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` will be loaded. that's where you can add your custom js or custom css.

Comment: OK but I would like some sample code please. Right now I tried to write some sample code in the `view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml` but the .js file was not included