# Change order of CSS and JS in the <head> section of the page

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, meta-tags, head

Where is the block with CSS and JS in the `<head></head>` rendered? And how to change the order of the elements from that section?

[image]

(this screenshot is from [Magento 2 demo](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/))

I'd like to change the order of elements in that section (and add more elements at the end) but I couldn't find any template file responsible for that part of the head, so it seems like it's rendered somewhere else.

A few elements from the head (e.g. the `viewport` meta tag) are added in this layout file `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
</head>
```

A few other elements are added in this layout file `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<head>
    <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
    <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
</head>
```

1. But what decides that in the end on the frontend the `requirejs/require.js` is placed **after** `css/styles-l.css`? Where is the code responsible for that?
2. Where is this element added to the head?

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/media/styles.css" />`

I know it is taken from the **Scripts and Style Sheets** field from the admin panel: Content -> Design -> Configuration -> HTML Head. But what decides that it is displayed right **after** `requirejs/require.js` and not after other CSS assets like `css/print.css`?

Comment: Check the following link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages

Comment: @Suman-PHP4U Thanks but I edited my question to better explain what I'm looking for.