# Call custom Js to particular page only Magento 2

Tags: extensions, custom, magento2.2, requirejs

I created a custom module in Magento 2, in this i am using one external js library and one my js file in which i put all my custom js to handle the extension whenever required suing the `requirejs-config.js`

IN `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Hestabit/ReviewRating/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

I want to load this file only on home page i.e `cms_index_index.xml` and cart page i.e  `cms_index_index.xml` in these file we use  to include the custom css or include custom phtml.

I used above xml to call my custom phtml only on those pages.
My `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/main",
    ],


     map: {
        '*': {
            'slickjs': 'NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/slick/slick',
            'sliderjs': 'NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/slick/tiny-slider'

        }
    },

    shim: {
        "slickjs": ["jquery"],
        "sliderjs": ["jquery"]

    }


};
```

In my main.js I am trying to get some id value which will be available only on home and cart page so on other pages it is throwing not found the error in console.

Answer (score 0):

I have added custom js in Product section at backend like below:

**app/code/Custom/Product/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <link src="Custom_Product::js/custom.js"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

Just path should be below location:

**app/code/Custom/Product/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom.js**

Comment: someone suggested that in a module we must not include the js in the way you suggested that directly in `<head>` , use `requirejs-config.js` did i understood them wrong ?

Comment: even if i use the way you suggested how can i prevent them from loading on all pages currently they are throwing the error on all pages wherever the js dont find the ids

Comment: this Custom_Product::   namespace will help to call on respect location only not on every page

Comment: Sir in my case my module is names as  `<link src="Namespace_ReviewRating::js/main.js"/>`

Comment: still i am not able to do the way you suggested sir

Comment: Ping me on Skype :  pramod.kharade . Will help you by sharing screen