# How to use third party jquery libraries in magento along with requirejs?

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I am bit new to requirejs and currently learning AMD pattern in requirejs.I want to use custom third-party jquery libraries in magento.

I have two questions:

1. How to use jquery scripts that are dependent on newer version of jquery as Magento comes preinstalled only with **jquery v-1.12.4**.Whenever I want to use libraries that depends on version **3.3.1** I can't use them.
2. How to define those third party libraries as AMD module so that I can use them in any template file?

After doing some googling, I came to know that to define any component as dependent on jquery I have to use [shim](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) config of requirejs.For example here is my code

```
var config = {
            'map': {
                '*': {
                    'somecomponent': 'js/somecomponent'
                }
            },
            'shim': {
                'somecomponent': {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                }
            }
 }
```

I have done all these things and still I can't use the function from somecomponent.Is it that to use code from **somecomponent.js** , I have to use [define](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) inside **somecomponent.js** and return/export some object so as to use in template files?

Is it that I have to do modifications inside **somecomponent.js** jquery library? If yes then what?

Script inside template looks like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','somecomponent'],function($, somecomponent) {
        somecomponent.init({
            //options object
        })
    })
</script>
```

And browser is giving an error- 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined**

**Note**:- Somecomponent is already using **$** inside it.

Comment: also add path in requiredJs  and check if it's work.  paths: {"somecomponent": 'js/somecomponent'}

Comment: I have added paths config with no luck.

Comment: Have checked it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages ?

Comment: Can you please explaint how to use exports within shim? I can't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you place the js in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/somecomponent.js`, you can call this js in requirejs like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['Vendor_Module/js/somecomponent'], function(some){
      //remaining code.........
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have put somecomponent.js directly at theme level directory i.e. inside <theme_dir>/web/js/somecomponent.js and requirejs-config.js in <theme_dir>/ directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **init** function inside your **js** file just try this one.i think this one work. Because i also have used this in one of my module.

If not work!! can you show your js code here !! so will understand better.

```
require(['jquery','somecomponent'],
        function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
       });
});
```