# Magento2: Undefined JS error

Tags: magento2

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /* Form with auto submit feature */
    $('form[data-auto-submit="true"]').submit();
});
```

I am getting undefined error

Comment: what is undefined? `$('form[data-auto-submit="true"]')` ?

Comment: i am getting error at top on define line

Comment: how do you include the file in your page?

Comment: <script src="mymodule_Custom::js/form-mini.js"/>

Comment: in my default.xml file

Comment: It does not work like that. If you include it int he header, the function `define` is not declared yet and you get that error. Read this for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages

Comment: i alredy tried this nee help can you provide working code