# Magento2: How to output the contents of an entire JS file into a phtml file?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, frontend, php-7.2

I defined a function in a block class as below to return the contents of an entire custom JS file, the path of which is stored in `$absolute_custom_js_file_path` . What is the right PHP function to be used inside the return statement so that my phtml file would get all the JS file contents? Thanks for the help.

```
    public function getAllPagesJSContent() {
    // Code to get the absolute path to the media directory.        
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();

    // Code to get the absolute path to the custom JS file.
    $absolute_custom_js_file_path = $mediaPath . 'pmm-custom/allpages.js';
    return __('What PHP function to use to read and return the contents of the JS file)');
}
```

Here is the phtml:

`<?php
echo $block->getAllPagesJSContent();
?>`

Comment: 1. Please dont use ObjectManager if You really dont need do it. Use __construct. 2. What You exactly need? Just display js content for customer or something else ?

Comment: Sure, I will definitely replace object manager by employing dependency injection. Yes, for  now, I just want to output it inside the head section within <script></script> so that it is visible only in the viewsource not to the visitors.

Comment: But whats Your purpose? It is a bit weird way for attach script to page. You can add js to specific page by xml layouts.

Comment: I need this script available across the site, and the `getAllPagesJSContent()` is going to be called by another custom JS file.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand Your purposes but it looks like dirty workaround. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages imo it should solve Your needs

Comment: Thanks for the link. I may switch to the best possible way to accomplish what I am trying to with the current approach once it is found.