# How to include external JS in adminhtml using requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, ui-form, requirejs-config.js

I try to include external JS `(fabric.js)` in my custom module.

I try so many different way but still not getting success. i don't understand what i missing below is my code.

1. Add external JS `(fabric.js)` under `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<adminhtml>/web/js/fabric.js`
2. Create `requirejs-config.js` under `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<adminhtml>/requirejs-config.js`

Add following code to `requirejs-config.js`

```
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

var config = {
 map: {
    '*': {            
        fabric: 'Namespace_Modulename/js/fabric'
    }
 }
};
```

I followed below link to achieve my thing but still not get success.

- [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/how-to-add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages)
- [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101671](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101671/magento-2-requirejs-config-js-in-themes/103070#103070)
- [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2)

Any other way to include external JS.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you insert it in `require` or `define` function?

Comment: You should try this with shim instead of map.

Comment: @Ramkishan i already try with `shim` but no luck

Comment: @LucScu i am not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: You need to initialize the javascript component, follow this doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html. `requirejs-config.js` is not required, it is only used to set the requirejs settings.

Comment: please check `requirejs-config.js` in `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US` if there is a entry for your external js if not then do setup upgrade and static content deploy

Comment: Can you show first lines of fabric.js ?

Comment: @BartZalas ok check `var fabric = fabric || { version: '2.4.2' };`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the javascript component like described in [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).

If you use the declarative notation using the `<script type="text/x-magento-init" />` tag you have to add to your .phtml

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    // components initialized without binding to an element
    "*": {
        "fabric": {} // the alias for "Namespace_Modulename/js/fabric" defined in requirejs-config.js
    }
}
</script>
```

That's it, your javascript component will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I don't required `phtml` file, i want o get this value in `html file.

Comment: Do you read the documentation linked? Take a look to imperative notation.

Comment: Yes i read it and try it but in `html file it is not working. for your efforts +1 :)

Comment: thx, but what happen if you use
<script>
require([
    'fabric'
], function ($) {
    alert('xxx);
    });
);
</script>

Comment: nothing it's not alert or also not get any error in console. strange!

Comment: how your .html is included in the page?

Comment: using UI component `<item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/image-preview</item>`

Comment: you post only a part of a code, i can't help you....i suppose that you are customising `category_form.xml` so you have `<item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>`. This element is binded to `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/file-uploader.js` so just copy from this example and you could obtain your target ;)

Comment: you are right! i override `file-uploader.js` file and i got success :) i ahve one other question should i ask?

Comment: I have a added a one hidden UI component field below file upload field and i want to append uploaded image name to hidden field value, i got file path name by using `return file.url;` in `file-uploader.js` file but i have a no idea how to set this path to hidden field value ad save data to database. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have to find the .php file that saves the form data to db and then maybe override it.

Answer (score 0):

Your fabric.js should start something like this (if you don't need without jQuery):

```
  define([ 
       "jquery" 
    ],
    function($) {
        "use strict"; 

        // Here your custom code...
     console.log('Hello'); 

        });
```

Check this require js app example, js files always have define(

https://github.com/volojs/create-template/tree/master/www

Or if you use shim in your require config file: a shim automatically adds a wrapper around a JavaScript library that makes it AMD-compatible / RequireJS-friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, without adding this fabric js is working fine.